# Trying to find which Sprite was clicked in array of sprites onTouchEnded

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-x, touch-event

I'm trying to detect which sprite was touched in an array of sprites and when it is touched to run an animation at the sprite which was touched. I have all the sprites placed in the map already but when the user touches any other sprite except for the first one the animation doesn't run. I'm using cocos2dx 3.5. Any help is appreciated thank you.

this is my onTouchesEnded

```
void BattleScreen::onTouchesEnded(const std::vector<cocos2d::Touch *> &touches, cocos2d::Event *event)
{

for (auto touch : touches)
{
    auto tapped = touch->getLocationInView();

    for (int i = 0; i < defenseSpots.size(); i++) {

        if(defenseSpot[i]->getBoundingBox().containsPoint(tapped))
        {

            sealAnimationSprite = Sprite::create("sealanimation5.png");
            sealAnimationSprite->setPosition(Point(defenseSpot[i]->getPosition().x, defenseSpot[i]->getPosition().y));
            this->addChild(sealAnimationSprite,20);

            // now lets create animation frames
            Vector<SpriteFrame*> sealAnimationFrames;
            sealAnimationFrames.reserve(5);
            sealAnimationFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("sealanimation5.png", Rect(0,0,100,100)));
            sealAnimationFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("sealanimation4.png", Rect(0,0,100,100)));
            sealAnimationFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("sealanimation3.png", Rect(0,0,100,100)));
            sealAnimationFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("sealanimation2.png", Rect(0,0,100,100)));
            sealAnimationFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("sealanimation.png",  Rect(0,0,100,100)));


            // create the animation out of the frames
            Animation* sealAnimation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(sealAnimationFrames, 0.01f);
            animateSeal = Animate::create(sealAnimation);

            // run it and repeat it forever
            sealAnimationSprite->runAction((animateSeal)); 
        }   
    }   
}
}
```

and here is my method where i create the sprites and place them

```
void BattleScreen::createDefenseSpots()
{
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++)
{
    defenseSpot[i] = Sprite::create("placement.png");
    if(i == 0)
        defenseSpot[i]->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 2 + origin.y));
    if (i == 1)
        defenseSpot[i]->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 1.4 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 3+ origin.y));
    if (i == 2)
        defenseSpot[i]->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 3.5 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 1.5 + origin.y));
    if (i == 3)
        defenseSpot[i]->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 2.5 + origin.x, visibleSize.height / 4+ origin.y));
    this->addChild(defenseSpot[i]);
    defenseSpots.push_back(defenseSpot[i]);

}
}
```

Everything adds to the scene correctly but the only sprite the will run the animation is the first one. Im guessing the loop isn't executing correctly but I'm not sure how to fix it?

I've also tried looping through like this

```
for(int i = 0;i < 4; i++){
...
}
```

Comment: I figured it out , I was using auto tapped = touch->getLocationInView(); when i should have been using auto tapped = touch->getLocation();

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , I was using

```
auto tapped = touch->getLocationInView();
```

when i should have been using

```
auto tapped = touch->getLocation();
```

Just in case anyone out there is making my same mistake.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct so other users can know that it has been solved.